# Display Navigation Drawer in each Activity after connecting Fragments with Activities (Android - Github tutorial)

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, navigation-drawer

I am trying to implement a navigation drawer (left slide menu) in my Android project.
 My application has a main activity till now, in which you could navigate to others with `Intent` method through buttons.

 
So, I searched for a navigation drawer and I found/followed the exact steps of **[THIS](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer)** tutorial. 
My code related to the menu is exactly the same, so for that reason, I am not posting it below.

---

**Related to my code:**

The three fragments that I created, were just extended the class `Fragment` and where completely empty.

The ONLY change from the code in the tutorial, is inside the `res/layout/activity_main.xml`, because I changed the `com.codepath.examples.navdrawerdemo.FragmentNavigationDrawer` to `'my_project's_name'.FragmentNavigationDrawer`.

---

---

**What I managed to do:**

I managed to create the menu that I want and display it ONLY if I make the `MainActivity.java` as the launcher inside the `AndroidManifest`. When I see the menu, I can go to each fragment through it, but I can't go to any of my Activities because I didn't link the fragments with the activities that I want. My menu, also does this transition that it should, so I am completely fine with the style of it.

---

**What I want to do:**
I just want to have the same menu inside every activity that I have already created, and when I click in an item in the menu, I want to navigate to an activity that I want BUT I want the activity to still display the menu.

I searched for solutions, but when I put back my first Activity as launcher in the `Android Manifest`, and set a layout for example inside the Fragment for it, it's just a useless layout. And when I tried to do an Intent to call my Activity inside the Fragment, the menu disappeared.

*P.S I didn't changed any of my Activitie's code or of their layouts. I added only the code from the tutorial!*

Comment: did you implement the Callback to your NavigationFragment in other activities? I mean the NavigationCallback, and its onNavigationItemSelected method.

Comment: No I didn't find how to do that. i only made an Intent or set layout inside the fragment. But that is not the solution.